# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J

Tags: java, opencv

Hey guys I've tried all the search, so obviously google doesn't help me ^^
I'm sure, that I've installed the opencv Library right, because the thing worked with earlier prototypes. All I've done is that I changed the main method a bit, so please keep close tabs on this. Function of the program: It streams from the webcam, gets the middle of the head and draw a path which follows your head.

```
Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.<init>(CascadeClassifier.java:58)
    at at.htlklu.tremoranalyzer.FaceDetector.<init>(FaceDetector.java:17)
    at at.htlklu.tremoranalyzer.Main.initComponents(Main.java:110)
    at at.htlklu.tremoranalyzer.Main.<init>(Main.java:40)
    at at.htlklu.tremoranalyzer.Main.main(Main.java:198)
```

//Main method

```
package at.htlklu.tremoranalyzer;

//In diesem Zwischenschritt vom TremorAnalyzer funktioniert das Zeichnen
//im Panel mit Linien, dem gelben Punkt und das Rechteck 
//um das Gesicht.


//Screenshot im Matura Ordner Screenshots.
//Datum: 4.11.2014
//------------------------
//Update: 3 Buttons die funktionieren
//Datum 7.11.2014


import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;



public class Main {
    private FaceDetector faceDetector;
    private Frame frame;
    private static FacePanelX facePanel;
    public static boolean state = true;

    public Main(){
        initComponents();
        initCamera();
        initProcessing();
    }

    private void initProcessing() {

        VideoCapture webCam = new VideoCapture(0);
        Mat webcam_image = new Mat();

        if (webCam.isOpened()) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (state) {
                webCam.read(webcam_image);
                if (!webcam_image.empty()) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }  
                    frame.setSize(webcam_image.width() +40 ,
                            webcam_image.height() +80 );




                    webcam_image = faceDetector.detect(webcam_image);
                    // Display the image
                    facePanel.matToBufferedImage(webcam_image);
                    Point center = faceDetector.getCenter();
                    if (center != null) {
                        facePanel.setFaceCenter(center);

                        facePanel.repaint();
                        facePanel.invalidate();
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println(" --(!) No captured frame from webcam !");
                    webCam.release();
                    break;
                }

            }
        }


        webCam.release();

    }





    private void initCamera() {

    }

    private void initComponents() {
        frame = new JFrame("WebCam Capture - Face detection");
        ((JFrame) frame).setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        faceDetector = new FaceDetector();
        frame.setSize(400, 400); // give the frame some size
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        JButton btnStopRecord = new JButton("Stop Recording");
        btnStopRecord.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                state = false;

            }
        });

        JButton btndrawLine = new JButton("Draw Path");
        btndrawLine.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                facePanel.getArray().clear();


            drawLine();


            }
        });
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(((JFrame) frame).getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(facePanel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 388, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(btnExit, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGap(37)
                            .addComponent(btnStopRecord, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 139, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGap(30)
                            .addComponent(btndrawLine, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 107, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(facePanel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 331, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(btnExit, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(btndrawLine, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(btnStopRecord, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        ((JFrame) frame).getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);

        frame.setVisible(true);




        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        facePanel = new FacePanelX();

    }






    public static void main(String arg[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Main m = new Main();
    } 

    private  static void drawLine(){        
        facePanel.setDrawLineActive(!facePanel.isDrawLineActive());
    }
}
```

//FacePanelX for drawing

```
package at.htlklu.tremoranalyzer;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;

public class FacePanelX extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage image;
    private boolean drawLineActive = false;
    private ArrayList<Point> array = new ArrayList<Point>();
    private Point faceCenter = new Point();


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
// getters, setters 

    public ArrayList<Point> getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    public void setArray(ArrayList<Point> array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public Point getFaceCenter() {
        return faceCenter;
    }

    public void setFaceCenter(Point point) {
        this.faceCenter = point;

        array.add(point);
    }


//  \getters, setters   
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   


    public FacePanelX() {
        super();

    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       


    public boolean matToBufferedImage(Mat matrix) {
        MatOfByte mb = new MatOfByte();
        Highgui.imencode(".jpg", matrix, mb);
        try {
            this.image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mb.toArray()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;

        }
        return true;
    }

//  \ matToBufferedImage    
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        if (this.image == null)
            return;

        g2d.drawImage(this.image, 10, 10, this.image.getWidth(),
                this.image.getHeight(), null);

        drawFaceRect(g2d);
        drawMiddle(g2d);
        if(drawLineActive)
        drawLine(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();

    }

//  \ paintComponent    
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       

    public void drawFaceRect(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawRect(((int) faceCenter.x - 31), (int) faceCenter.y - 31, 62, 62);


    }

    public void drawMiddle(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillOval(1280 / 2, 720 / 2, 10, 10);


    }


//  \ drawRect, drawMiddle  
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   


    public void drawLine(Graphics2D g) {
//      state = false;

//      if (!((int) faceCenter.x > 350 && (int) faceCenter.y > 280)
//              || ((int) faceCenter.x < 280 && (int) faceCenter.y < 190)) {
//          state = true;

//      }

        Point bufP = new Point(-1, -1);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);

        if (array.size() > 1) {


            for (Point p : array) {
                System.out.println("p: " + p.x + " " + p.y);

                g.fillOval((int) p.x, (int) p.y, 2, 2);

                if (!(bufP.x == -1 && bufP.y == -1)) {

                    g.drawLine((int) bufP.x, (int) bufP.y, (int) p.x, (int) p.y);

                }

                bufP.x = p.x;
                bufP.y = p.y;
            }
        }

    }


//  \ methode drawLine  
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

    public boolean isDrawLineActive() {
        return drawLineActive;
    }

    public void setDrawLineActive(boolean drawLineActive) {
        this.drawLineActive = drawLineActive;
    }



}
```

//FaceDetector for CascadeClassifier

```
package at.htlklu.tremoranalyzer;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class FaceDetector {
    private CascadeClassifier faceCascade;
    private Point center;
    /**
     * 
     */
    public FaceDetector() {
        faceCascade = new CascadeClassifier("src/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
        if (faceCascade.empty()) {
            System.out.println("--(!)Error loading cascade classifier\n");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Face classifier loaded up");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Does some basic preprocessing
     * 
     * @param inputframe The frame to be processed
     * @return The processed matrix
     */

    public Mat detect(Mat inputframe) {
        Mat mRgba = new Mat();
        Mat mGrey = new Mat();
        MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();
        inputframe.copyTo(mRgba);
        inputframe.copyTo(mGrey);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGrey, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Imgproc.equalizeHist(mGrey, mGrey);
        faceCascade.detectMultiScale(mGrey, faces);

        for (Rect rect : faces.toArray()) {
            center = new Point(rect.x + rect.width * 0.5, rect.y + rect.height
                    * 0.5);
        }
        return mRgba;
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    public Point getCenter() {
        return center;
    }
}

// \class FaceDetector
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: please move `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);` from initComponents() to a static block, so the dll gets loaded before any ctor gets called.

Comment: It doesn't help. Actually, the problem may exist in the library itself. Loading it looks done well